# How to make Thompson 516 DSL modem re-establish connection automatically on power loss?

Tags: modem, dsl

I don't know why my DSL modem works like this. Whenever there's a power loss, the modem will just sit around in a disconnected state until someone goes into the web interface and click "Connect". As the grid in my neighbor is not terribly reliable, I would find myself doing this a couple times a month. And since I'm always not at the building at all time, I'd find myself racing back just to click on that stupid button. How do I make the modem keep trying when there's no connection?

Comment: There probably isn't a built-in mechanism (really don't know about that particular modem) but you can use a script (such as autoit or autohotkey if you're using windows) to detect if the connection went down and then automate getting into the modem to click the button (autoit has a good IE automation library).

Comment: @MaQleod or if one knows the linux command when telnetting in. my 546 lets me telnet in though I don't know the command

Comment: this isn't quite what you're looking for but a UPS might help!

Comment: Wow, that's an oldie. These devices should be able to reconnect on power-on/signal loss. Maybe these topics are useful. [One](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1751702) and [Two](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r24757713-Why-can-t-my-Thomson-ST516-connect-all-by-itself-). Look for your setting of detect-lop and/or demanddial. For a complete CLI-guide of your modem see [here](http://www.technicolorgateways.nl/Producten/Basic/ST546/ST546-v6_CLI.pdf). (It's for the ST516 v6, ST536 v6 and ST546 v6) (i take it you have a v6?)